# Checksum a group of folders to another group of folders using md5sum

Tags: command-line, md5sum, checksums

I copied three folders from three different directories. I want to check the copies over the originals with checksum. Is this possible in the command line?

Answer (score 3):

Without more details from you, it's hard to give an answer that's more specific than "yes it is".

Although it would be possible to script something using `find` and `md5sum`, it will almost certainly be easier to use the `--checksum` option of `rsync` **in dry run mode** (using the `--dry-run` or `-n` flag) as described here [Verify backup integrity with rsync, sed, cat, and tee](https://techblog.jeppson.org/2014/10/verify-backup-integrity-with-rsync-sed-cat-and-tee/).

Since you copied the directories from diverse locations, you will likely need to do it three times - once for each source directory i.e.

```
rsync -Pahn --checksum path/to/originaldir1/ path/to/newdir1/
rsync -Pahn --checksum path/to/originaldir2/ path/to/newdir2/
rsync -Pahn --checksum path/to/originaldir3/ path/to/newdir3/
```

(you may be able to automate this somewhat, depending on your directory names and paths - but for 3 dirs it may not be worth the effort).

The output will consist of a single line for each filename whose checksum differs e.g.

```
$ rsync -Pahn --checksum olddir/ newdir/
sending incremental file list
subdir2/file
```